# What character encoding does C++ use?

Tags: c++

I assumed C-strings using `char` are always ASCII-encoded, but I want to know if this is the case. It's a significant question, because surely functions such as `toupper` will need to know the encoding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204453/c-standard-character-set-and-string-encoding-specification

Comment: Why does `toupper` need to know the encoding?! `if (c == 'a') return 'A';`

Comment: @KerrekSB True, but wouldn't that be an inefficient implementation?

Comment: @NeilKirk: nope: `#define toupper(c) (((c) - 'a') + 'A')` works regardless of character set.

Comment: @KerrekSB: depending on the encoding, some characters may be a lower case letter or a non-letter symbol.

Comment: @NeilKirk: That wasn't your question. You claimed it would be impossible to implement `toupper` without knowing the character set; I say that it's perfectly possible.

Comment: @KerrekSB I can ask new questions!

Comment: @KerrekSB In Windows-1252, 'Ž' - 'ž' != 'A' - 'a'